Could not resolve com.github.sabpaisa-android:sabpaisa:0.0.2
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.github.sabpaisa-android:sabpaisa:0.0.2.
Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/sabpaisa-android/sabpaisa/0.0.2/sabpaisa-0.0.2.pom'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.sabpaisa-android:sabpaisa:0.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.github.sabpaisa-android:sabpaisa:0.0.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/sabpaisa-android/sabpaisa/0.0.2/sabpaisa-0.0.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/sabpaisa-android/sabpaisa/0.0.2/sabpaisa-0.0.2.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
      > Could not resolve com.github.sabpaisa-android:sabpaisa:0.0.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/sabpaisa-android/sabpaisa/0.0.2/sabpaisa-0.0.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/sabpaisa-android/sabpaisa/0.0.2/sabpaisa-0.0.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

1 change version of sdk (implementation 'com.github.sabpaisa-android:sabpaisa:0.0.2')
2 follow sabpaisa official doc.

Any reason why you use 0.0.2 instead of a more recent version? You can also compare with the reference code https://bitbucket.org/sabpaisa-wp-29/android-native-kotlin/src/master/, they use the version 1.0.1 there.

thanku bro, it is working for me
